# comparing parsed hijri date with getdate() returns error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query, it parses hijri date in table correctly:

```
 select convert(datetime ,my_col ,131)  cc from my_table
   where 
   my_col is not null;
```

It returns correct data:

```
2022-11-27 00:00:00.000
2022-11-24 00:00:00.000
2022-11-24 00:00:00.000
```

while this one gives error

```
   select * from 
   (select convert(datetime ,my_col ,131)  cc from my_table
   where 
   my_col is not null
   ) ff where ff.cc < getdate();
```

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 12.
> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

any help ?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] please? What happens if you change `CONVERT` to `TRY_CONVERT`?

Comment: TRY_CONVERT works, but why ? and also does this mean that some records are discarded ??
for reproduclble example, the point is that `convert()` worked , but comparison with `getdate()` didnt

Comment: Some dates in your data cannot be converted. Your query might work sometimes, other times it won't. You need to fix those dates.

Comment: There is likely some order of operations going on here causing the issue, alongside bad data. Without an [mre] difficult to suggest more.

Comment: datetime is based on the gregorian calendar and starts around 1753 IIRC.  Please use datetime2 instead which should be able to store the hijri date

Comment: Always always use `TRY_CONVERT` if there is a possibility that the conversion may happens at the wrong point. The compiler is free to push `WHERE` conditions around, and may execute one before the other

Comment: @Charlieface even with nested queries??
can I force it to run queries in order then ??

Comment: Problem is that the compiler is simplifying this to `where my_col is not null and convert(datetime ,my_col ,131) < getdate()` and then it is possibly reordering those two conditions. The only way to ensure this works as you expect is with a `CASE` expression which is (normally) guaranteed not to reorder. The only thing unclear is why the first query *does* work, what happens if you execute it with no `where` at all?